# wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 4)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an instance method thats accepting 4 inputs

```
class Foo
  def baz(a, b, c, d)
    puts 'something'
  end
end
```

I am writing spec for the instance method and i have

```
let(:resp) {
  Foo.new.baz (
    a: '97334',
    b: '38',
    c: '0001110000',
    d: 'N')
}
```

I tried changing it to the one below but no luck

```
let(:resp) {
  Foo.new.baz '97334', '38', '0001110000','N')
}
```

why am i getting wrong number of arguments at instance method in Foo class?

Thanks

Comment: in your last code snippet, you have an extra parenthesis at the end. is that a typo on stackoverflow or is it in your actual code?

Comment: "why am i getting wrong number of arguments" - because you have four positional parameters, but actually pass it one hash object. The second snippet of yours will work, if you deal with the extra parenthesis.

Comment: Note that Ruby is actually sensitive to whitespace. `puts 1, 2, 3` is the same as `puts(1, 2, 3)` but not the same as `puts (1, 2, 3)`. If you're going to use parentheses in a method call then you don't want a space before the opening parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
let(:resp) {
  Foo.new.baz(
    '97334',
    '38',
    '0001110000',
    'N'
  )
}
```

You are passing keyword arguments which could be thought of as passing one `Hash`. So your code is basically equivalent to:

```
params = Hash.new
params[:a] = '97334'
params[:b] = '38'
params[:c] = '0001110000'
params[:d] = 'N'
let(:resp){
    Foo.new.baz(params)
}
```

This example above obviously only has 1 argument.

Another way to solve this would be parameterizing the function call:

```
class Foo
  def baz(a:, b:, c:, d:)
    puts 'something'
  end
end
```

In general this is preferred when there are many args to a function, because it does not require the function user to know the specific order of the function arguments, only which arguments are needed.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby <= 1.9, there are no named parameters, but you can achieve the same effect with a hash. The reason you get an error saying you only have one argument is because ruby assumes you are passing a single hash rather than 4 parameters. You can make it work like so:

```
class Foo
  def baz(myhash)
    puts "#{myhash[:a]}, #{myhash[:b]}"
  end
end

Foo.new.baz(a: "hello", b: "world) #=> "hello, world"
```

In ruby 2.0, named parameters exist, but they can only be optional:

```
class Foo
  def baz(a: "hi", b: "mum")
    puts "#{myhash[:a]}, #{myhash[:b]}"
  end
end

Foo.new.baz(a: "hello", b: "world) #=> "hello, world"
Foo.new.baz() #=> "hi, mum"
```

In ruby >= 2.1, named params can be optional OR required. you can make named params required by specifying them without default values like so:

```
class Foo
  def baz(a:, b:)
    puts "#{myhash[:a]}, #{myhash[:b]}"
  end
end

Foo.new.baz(a: "hello", b: "world) #=> "hello, world"
```

In all of these rubies, your last code snippet should work if you remove the extra parenthesis:

```
class Foo
  def baz(a, b, c, d)
    puts 'something'
  end
end

Foo.new.baz '97334', '38', '0001110000','N'
```

Comment: +Named parameters are not _necessarily_ optional >=2.1. If you do not initialize them then creation will fail.

Comment: @whodini9 what do you mean? my understanding is that in ruby 2.0 you cannot declare named parameters without default values- it will give you a syntax error.

Comment: just saw your edit. i agree that in 2.1 you can have optional AND required named params. my answer wasn't clear enough. i'll update it.